# Llenar List en ASP.NET con API

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Recibo información desde una API a mi aplicación asp.net mvc c#,y la data que recibo es correcta, el modelo que recibo es el siguiente:

```
public class Result
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string fotografia { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

la clase RootObject es un encabezado de mi consulta y la clase Result es para una lista, desde la data que recibo del API(que viene en formato JSON) solo trae dos atributos de Result, que son name y url, el campo foto lo lleno realizando un susbtring de url de la siguiente manera

```
foreach (var item in Encabezado.results)
{
    string numero = item.url.Substring(item.url.Length - 2, 1);
    var asignar = new Result
    {
        url = item.url,
        name = item.name,
        fotografia = numero
    };
    ListaPokemon.Add(asignar);
}
```

sin embargo el campo queda null, nunca recibe la data, y es aqui donde tengo el inconveniente ya que el substring se ejecuta correctamente, pero no agrega la información correspondiente a fotografia.

La cadena JSON es la siguiente:

```
{
    "count": 964,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "bulbasaur",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
        },
        {
            "name": "ivysaur",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Consejo cuando publiques código no uses las tres comillas invertidas y/o la etiqueta de algún lenguaje, lo mejor en estos casos es seleccionar tu código y presionar: `ctrl + k` o seleccionar tu código y presionar `{}` en el editor de texto, de todos modos quedará coloreado

Comment: Seria excelente que tbn colocaras el JSON que obtienes en la consulta. Adicional, si mal y no me equivoco el SubString que realizas es para obtener el penultimo caracter de la cadena, ese es el valor que intentas obtener?.

Comment: Tomado en cuenta tu comentario Aprendiz, Orlando agregué el JSON que recibo de la API, y ene efecto busco tomar el número entre las barras diagonales casi al final de la cadena, que la variable numero está tomando correctamente, pero fotografia no recibe el valor y no sé porqué.

Comment: No le veo ningun problema, asi como esta deberia funcionar. Pregunta: estas seguro que al momento de obtener el valor de fotografia utilizas `ListaPokemon`?

Comment: En efecto Orlando, agregué una imagen donde reviso ListaPokemon y fotografía tiene valor, pero en la vista se pasa null, pero los otros dos campos van con la data correcta.

Comment: Ya revisaste que le estas pasando el modelo correcto a la vista?, desde el controlador que modelo le pasas a la vista y en la vista que tipo de datos le defines al modelo.

Comment: Me parece que si, ya que los campos name y url si se están cargando correctamente a la vista con el modelo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no intentas decorar cada propiedad con el atributo `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]` y la clase con `[DataContract]` (no olvides incluir `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`)? Con eso forzarías a que cada propiedad sea serializada.

Comment: Kroneaux seguí tu sugerencia, el resultado es el mismo.